# Separating models

Tags: geometry

I have purchased a FBX / OBJ file.

Unfortunately it's not really separated.

It seems to be the same model in different "poses".
When I delete just the "inlay" object (the foam like object that is put into the weapon cage and which is shown on the "bottom" of the screenshot), the UVs stay intact.

I can however not easily delete the upper model because it's tightly stacked on the other model.

How could I most comfortably separate these models?

Thank you!
[image]

Comment: Try this: unselect all; Change the selection mode to Faces; Hit L over some meshes to select the connected meshes; Hit P to separate the selected meshes.

Comment: Thank you, that worked when I imported it as an FBX. I first tried it as an OBJ, and that wouldn't work.

Comment: Can you please make your comment the answer? Can you also please note that L should be pressed repeatedly on each surface that should be included? That did the job perfectly for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the selection mode to Faces.

Hit  <kbd>L</kbd>  over some meshes to select the connected meshes. Repeat it to include other meshes.

Hit  <kbd>P</kbd>  to separate the selected meshes.